# CI trigger child pipeline only on changes and mark as success if not triggered

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab ci pipeline like this (taken from their [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/pipeline_architectures.html#child--parent-pipelines))

```
stages:
  - triggers

trigger_reports:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: reports/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes:
        - reports/*

trigger_storage:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: storage/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes:
        - storage/*
```

This works well but marks the overall pipeline as failed if the child pipeline was not triggered. [image: gitlab status]. The message is

> downstream pipeline cannot be created, No stages/jobs for this
> pipeline

How can I only run a child pipeline on changes but mark the run as successful if it wasn't triggered?

I tried to add

```
  rules:
    - changes:
        - reports/*
    - exists:
        - reports/*
```

But that also triggers the child pipeline.